# problem with connection of facebook in my app for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have complete code of facebook connection. But When i dragged the complete code into my application then 112 errors will occurs. wherever i have use use that code "FBConnect/FBConnectGlobal.h"Then error will arises "FBConnect/FBConnectionGlobal.h" No such file or directory. Even i have given all the path in project setting/project active setting.
So please tell me some solution how to rectify some solution. and also tell me exact place where i have set the path and what to give in that path

Thanks

Comment: if you have dragged and dropped files to your project folder and set "copy items to project folder" option to true then you need to change "FBConnect/FBConnectGlobal.h"  to "FBConnectGlobal.h" and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

I think Ayaz is right, you checked of the "copy items.." box. However, try and start over, deleting the FBConnect folder and do it without copying it. If you start changing the headers you will probably have to do it for all the classes and if there is an update to the FBConnect library you need to start all over again.